# Exploration Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, agent

Massively edited this question to make it easier to understand.

Given an environment with arbitrary dimensions and arbitrary positioning of an arbitrary number of obstacles, I have an agent exploring the environment with a limited range of sight (obstacles don't block sight). It can move in the four cardinal directions of NSEW, one cell at a time, and the graph is unweighted (each step has a cost of 1). Linked below is a map representing the agent's (yellow guy) current belief of the environment at the instant of planning. Time does not pass in the simulation while the agent is planning.

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img913/9274/qRsazT.jpg

What exploration algorithm can I use to maximise the cost-efficiency of utility, given that revisiting cells are allowed? Each cell holds a utility value. Ideally, I would seek to maximise the sum of utility of all cells SEEN (not visited) divided by the path length, although if that is too complex for any suitable algorithm then the number of cells seen will suffice. There is a maximum path length but it is generally in the hundreds or higher. (The actual test environments used on my agent are at least 4x bigger, although theoretically there is no upper bound on the dimensions that can be set, and the maximum path length would thus increase accordingly)

I consider BFS and DFS to be intractable, A* to be non-optimal given a lack of suitable heuristics, and Dijkstra's inappropriate in generating a single unbroken path. Is there any algorithm you can think of? Also, I need help with loop detection, as I've never done that before since allowing revisitations is my first time.

One approach I have considered is to reduce the map into a spanning tree, except that instead of defining it as a tree that connects all cells, it is defined as a tree that can see all cells. My approach would result in the following:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img910/3050/HGu40d.jpg

In the resultant tree, the agent can go from a node to any adjacent nodes that are 0-1 turn away at intersections. This is as far as my thinking has gotten right now. A solution generated using this tree may not be optimal, but it should at least be near-optimal with much fewer cells being processed by the algorithm, so if that would make the algorithm more likely to be tractable, then I guess that is an acceptable trade-off. I'm still stuck with thinking how exactly to generate a path for this however.

Comment: You can check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping.

Comment: why not A* with heuristic based on number of cells seen

Comment: @perreal Do you know what exact algorithms from SLAM I can apply to my problem? My agent is able to access the map's dimensions and knows its own exact position at all times, so it only needs to generate an exploration path in tractable time and loop detection.

Comment: @nkcode I believe using the number of cells seen is a poor heuristic utility/cost measure to use for A* and would not give an optimal solution

Comment: For reference, see this for a similar problem. The spanning tree approach I considered above is an attempt to reduce my problem to be as similar to this one as possible http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55221/need-an-efficient-algorithm-to-visit-all-nodes-of-a-graph-revisiting-edges-and

Comment: The environment seems to be finite; is this the case? Are the utility values nonnegative? If so, it seems to make no sense to optimize the utility alone, but the ratio of utility over movement; is this a suitable approach?

Comment: If I get it right you can see every cell that is "in line" with the agent. In this case I think your approach is good. At that point the problem is reduced to TSP to visit all the nodes of the tree (which is more a graph).

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the mission is to "see" the whole world, and at every cell you see a part of the world. You want to choose the least number of cells to cover as much of the world as possible. Then this is a version of the Maximum coverage problem which is NP-complete. There is some approximations on it though. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem

Comment: Cosider `sight=0`, it means you need to visit all points in order to "see" them. This is exactly the Hamiltonian Path Problem (HPP), so given an instance of HPP, create an instance of your problem with sight=0, and answer "true" if and only if the "best" solution is 1:1 matching from length of path and number of cells seen. This basically proves the problem is NP-Hard, and there is no known efficient solution to it (even when knowing the obstacles locations before starting to move).

Comment: Ok the problem is np-hard, still there are ways to solve some of these. For instance GAs are good for TSP. And visiting all the cells adiacent to an obstacle solves the problem for agent with infinite sight (which I guess is the case).

Comment: @Codor The environment's dimensions are arbitrary, but yes in each simulation the values are fixed within integer range. The utility values are nonneg. Ratio of utility over movement is actually what I meant - I'm maximising cost efficiency of utility. I actually have a fuel limit, but most of the time, I can aim to see the whole world as per Krycke's interpretation, although there can be cases where there is a maximum path length (I have a fuel limit). But please focus on the general algorithm and ignore the fuel part, that's digressing. Thanks!

Comment: @amit sight > 0, actually. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @Demplo The agent does not have infinite sight. The environment is only partially accessible to the agent. However, obstacles only block movement, not sight. The agent can't move through obstacles, but can see behind it. The line of sight is a square centred around the agent.

Comment: If the agent only knows what he's seen so far, and there's no general rule about the utility of each tile compared to it's neighbours then I think you can only maximize utility by covering as much of the map as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is very similar to a canonical Reinforcement Learning (RL) problem, the Grid World. I would formalize it as a standard Markov Decision Process (MDP) and use any RL algorithm to solve it.

The formalization would be:

- States `s`: your `NxM` discrete grid.
- Actions `a`: `UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT`.
- Reward `r`: the value of the cells that the agent can see from the destination cell `s'`, i.e. `r(s,a,s') = sum(value(seen(s'))`.
- Transition function: `P(s' | s, a) = 1` if `s'` is not out of the boundaries or a black cell, `0` otherwise.

Since you are interested in the average reward, the discount factor is `1` and you have to normalize the cumulative reward by the number of steps. You also said that each step has cost one, so you could subtract 1 to the immediate reward `r`at each time step, but this would not add anything since you will already average by the number of steps.

Since the problem is discrete the policy could be a simple softmax (or Gibbs) distribution.

As solving algorithm you can use Q-learning, which guarantees the optimality of the solution provided a sufficient number of samples. However, if your grid is too big (and you said that there is no limit) I would suggest policy search algorithms, like policy gradient or relative entropy (although they guarantee convergence only to local optima). You can find something about Q-learning basically everywhere on the Internet. For a recent survey on policy search I suggest [this](http://www.ausy.tu-darmstadt.de/uploads/Site/EditPublication/PolicySearchReview.pdf).

The cool thing about these approaches is that they encode the exploration in the policy (e.g., the temperature in a softmax policy, the variance in a Gaussian distribution) and will try to maximize the cumulative long term reward as described by your MDP. So usually you initialize your policy with a high exploration (e.g., a complete random policy) and by trial and error the algorithm will make it deterministic and converge to the optimal one (however, sometimes also a stochastic policy is optimal).
The main difference between all the RL algorithms is how they perform the update of the policy at each iteration and manage the tradeoff exploration-exploitation (how much should I explore VS how much should I exploit the information I already have).

As suggested by Demplo, you could also use Genetic Algorithms (GA), but they are usually slower and require more tuning (elitism, crossover, mutation...).

I have also tried some policy search algorithms on your problem and they seems to work well, although I initialized the grid randomly and do not know the exact optimal solution. If you provide some additional details (a test grid, the max number of steps and if the initial position is fixed or random) I can test them more precisely.